# "Inherit" background without being transparent?

Tags: css, background-color

Is it possible to make an element effectively inherit its background color from its nearest ancestor that has one, without making it transparent? (I realize `background-color` isn't an inherited property, I'm using the term loosely.)

My specific issue is with sticky table headers: When the table scrolls, the cells sliding up under the headers show through the headers because the headers are transparent.

I could solve it by giving the headers an explicit background color, but then I have to maintain the background color in multiple places (potentially multiple stylesheets). I'd rather have a small bit of reusable CSS I can use...

- ...without explicit colors, and
- ...without requiring CSS variables or similar

(But if the answer is "you have to," well, that's the answer.)

My structure is:

```html
<div class="app">
    <div>
        Irrelevant stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                (rows)
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.app {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 80vh;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}

.sticky {
    overflow: auto;
}

.sticky th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* I don't want to use a color or CSS variable here:
    background-color: cornsilk;
    */
}
```

Live Example:

```css
/* Fill the page */
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* box sizing reset */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* No cellspacing in tables by default */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.app {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 80vh;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}

.sticky {
    overflow: auto;
}

.sticky th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    /* I don't want to use a color or CSS variable here:
    background-color: cornsilk;
    */
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <div>
        Irrelevant stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my naïvety I had great hopes for `background-color: currentcolor` but, well, it does what it says it does: Uses the current *color*, rather than background color.

*(And yes, the `table` really is for a table, not layout.*  *)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a particularly elegant way to achieve what you're after without variables. These suggestions seem self-evident, but you could write a separate CSS selector to do it:

```css
.app,
.app .sticky th {
  background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

Or share a common class between them (again, suboptimal):

```html
<div class="app some-other-class">
<th class="some-other-class">
```

A custom property would be my only other suggestion, but you said you'd like to avoid variables.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I'm being unreasonable trying to avoid variables. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might use CSS variable, I believe it's a good usecase for it:

```css
/* Fill the page */
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* box sizing reset */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* No cellspacing in tables by default */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.app {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 80vh;
    --bgcolor: cornsilk;
    background-color: var(--bgcolor);
}

.sticky {
    overflow: auto;
}

.sticky th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: var(--bgcolor);
    /* I don't want to use a color explicitly here:
    background-color: cornsilk;
    */
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <div>
        Irrelevant stuff here
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Column</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A</td></tr>
                <tr><td>B</td></tr>
                <tr><td>C</td></tr>
                <tr><td>D</td></tr>
                <tr><td>E</td></tr>
                <tr><td>F</td></tr>
                <tr><td>G</td></tr>
                <tr><td>H</td></tr>
                <tr><td>I</td></tr>
                <tr><td>J</td></tr>
                <tr><td>K</td></tr>
                <tr><td>L</td></tr>
                <tr><td>M</td></tr>
                <tr><td>N</td></tr>
                <tr><td>O</td></tr>
                <tr><td>P</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
                <tr><td>R</td></tr>
                <tr><td>S</td></tr>
                <tr><td>T</td></tr>
                <tr><td>U</td></tr>
                <tr><td>V</td></tr>
                <tr><td>W</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP explicitly said "without requiring variables".

Comment: @rayhatfield, yes, `but if that's the answer, that's the answer.`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I think there is no better solution. You can `inherit` from the parent only, so that's it -- variable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you can set `background-color: inherit` and parent's value will be used. And yes, you have to use variable, or set it explicitly like ray suggests.

Comment: @Kosh - Thanks for the info! Sounds like I'm being unreasonable trying to avoid variables. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can inherit if you use `.app * { background-color: inherit;}`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it's not inherited automatically like `font-size` or `color` but you can set it to `inherit`. Try.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, example: https://jsfiddle.net/urmkaes3/

Comment: @Kosh - Not sure why I never replied, but `inherit` doesn't work in this case; https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/vjwn9ym1/.